# onMove() or onCursor() or onSelection() trigger in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, selection

I've looked at the [documentation for triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/), but couldn't find what I wanted. I essentially want to auto-fill certain spreadsheet cells when the cursor/selection moves to the cell.

For example, say I want any cell in column 'B' that is empty to be filled with the current time when it is highlighted.

How should I be doing that? I see [Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets#custom_menus_and_user_interfaces) refers to [<s>`UIService`</s>](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/uiapp) and [`HtmlService`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/), but I didn't find anything about triggers for when current cell changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your particular example, I would suggest creating a custom function [Docs for Custom Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_custom_functions) (using apps script) which produces the current time and enters the value in the cell. It doesn't need parameters either.  You could then call the function with something as simple as:

```
=time()
```

Add a few clicks for copy and paste, and you have a lot of functionality to play with.

Built in functions which produce the current time may or may not update as you reload the spreadsheet.

Comment: Perhaps I am looking at the wrong docs, but I couldn't figure out how to read the current value of the cell. Is there some API to look at the current cell's value?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=en#getValue()

Comment: Note that custom functions are expected to be deterministic - the output should depend only on the input. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#arguments

Answer (score 0):

There are no triggers for the events you describe, and while you may post a request on the issue tracker, I would not expect to see such triggers implemented.

Using existing capabilities, the closest you could get would be a menu-driven function that fills the current cell with a timestamp. Hardly as automatic as you are looking for.